# regex to replace specific characters while capturing the rest of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using notepad++

I need to replace `", "` with `,`  on a line beginning exclusively with `genre:`  and no where else in the document, while maintaining all of the other content in the line. I will be applying the search/replace to an entire folder, so I need to be as precise as I can.

Examples

```
genre: "drama", "thriller", "mystery", "espionage"
genre: "drama", "sci-fi"
```

should look like this:

```
genre: "drama, thriller, mystery, espionage"
genre: "drama, sci-fi"
```

I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how to do that without capturing an unlimited and unknown  number of groups before and after each instance of `", "`, while also keeping the first word and colon: `genre:` . I'm pretty sure I have to capture the entire group between the first and last `"`, and then replace `", "` with just `,`  within that group, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Obviously what I have here isn't going to do the trick.

```
find what: ^genre: "(.*)", "(.*)", "(.*)", "(.*)"
replace with: genre: "$1, $2, $3, $4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Find: (?:\G(?!^)|^genre:\h*").*?\K",\h*"
Replace: ,<SPACE>
```

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^genre:\h*")` - end of the previous match position or `genre:`, zero or more horizontal whitespaces and `"` at the start of string (here, line)
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - omit the matched text
- `",\h*"` - consume `",`, then zero or more horizontal whitespaces, and then a `"` (this will be replaced with `,` + space)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zhLVEa/1):

[image]

Comment: Wiktor Thanks so much! That `\K` is exactly what I was looking for. I could not quite figure out the first part of the pipe, but I think I have it now.  Is this an ok explanation of what it is going on: The `\K` only applies to the `.*?`  before it (excluding the first group). So once `^genre: "` has been found, it selects `.*?` then ignores that to find *the first* instance of `", "` which is replaced with `, `.  But it doesn't find the next instance. For that I need to say: repeat the search starting at the beginning of the last match (`\G`), again, excluding `.*?` because of the `\K`.

Comment: @lise There are two things that need adjusting in this understanding: `\K` applies to the *text* that was so far matched and consumed and placed into Group 0 of the match (the overall match value). It does not apply to just `.*?`. `\G(?!^)` matches the *end* of the previous match, not its start position. Please consider accepting if it worked for you.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code then,   `Updated Answer`

Find: `(?:^genre|\G)(?!^).*?\K", "`
Replace All: `,`     there is a space after ","

[image]

Comment: Haji, that captures more than it is supposed to. It finds and replaces in lines that do not start with or contain "genre". It caught all of these:
aliases: "A Sunday in Kigali", "Un dimanche à Kigali"
genre: "drama", "foreign", "romance", "sci-fi"
"Jean says yes", "Martha says no".

Comment: Updated the answer